# How do i make repeatable program

Tags: c, do-while

pls help me how to make my program repeatable

```
char name[99];

printf("Please Input your Complete Name: ");
scanf(" %[^\n]",name);

printf("%s\n", name);

printf("enter y or Y to continue");
scanf("%c", &redo);
while((redo == 'y') || (redo == 'Y'));
```

is my code is correct ? correct me if im wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while` at the bottom is a loop with an empty body because you have a `;` right after the condition instead of a statement or a bracketed group of statements.

For this you actually want `do..while`, which will run the loop at least once:

```
char redo;
char name[99];
do {

    printf("Please Input your Complete Name: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]",name);

    printf("%s\n", name);


    printf("enter y or Y to continue");
    scanf("%c", &redo);
} while((redo == 'y') || (redo == 'Y'));
```

Comment: how to do 'y' is to continue and 'Y' is to exit ?

Comment: @johnkenneth The condition at the bottom should contain what is required for the loop to continue.  So if only `'y'` should continue the loop, you would change the condition to `} while (redo == 'y');`

Comment: should i need to make a loop 2 loop for y and Y ?

Comment: @johnkenneth http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do

In while, any expression which is contextually convertible to bool. This expression is evaluated after each iteration, and if it yields false, the loop is exited.

Comment: @johnkenneth If you want to continue on just `'y'`, use `} while (redo == 'y');`.  If you want to continue on either `'y'` or `'Y'`, use `} while ((redo == 'Y') || (redo == 'y');` as you had before.

Comment: @dbush in addition, be careful for using scanf with %c. If more strings in input buffer, abnormal sequence could happen. You can use getc or, flush buffer.

Comment: @dbush what if i put my program in a menu display y is to continue and Y to go back to menu

Comment: @johnkenneth Displaying the menu would be in the body of your loop.

Comment: @johnkenneth Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: @johnkenneth You can use nested while loop (outer as include menu, programs. inner to get input) or, also goto (not good design. but still sometimes used in some areas)

Comment: } while ((redo == 'Y') || (redo == 'y')); the (redo == 'y') wont go exit it also go repeat

Comment: @johnkenneth Then post your updated code (without removing the existing code) along with your input and output.

Comment: @dbush }while(redo == 'y');

  if(redo ='Y')
   return 0;
is this correct ?

Comment: @johnkenneth  You don't need the `if`.  You're already outside of the loop.